# Magento Cart Event Items Logging

Tags: php, magento

I have the following magento code in a  custom module sitting in my local folder.

```
public function ProofOfConecept(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    //checkout_cart_save_before
    Mage::log('ProofOfConecept called - 2', null, 'proofLog.log');

    $cart = $observer->getEvent()->getCart();
    if($cart != NULL)
    {
        Mage::log('$cart contains data!', null, 'proofLog.log');
        $items = $cart->getItems();
        if($items != NULL)
        {
            Mage::log('$items has the following -- '.$items, null, 'proofLog.log');
        }else{
            Mage::log('$items is null??', null, 'proofLog.log');
        }
    }else
    {
        Mage::log('sorry Cart is null :(', null, 'proofLog.log');
    }


}
```

The code above is my method to call when an event is fired,
Below is the config.xml code

```
<events>
        <checkout_cart_save_before>
            <observers>
                <dotnetit_eccbundle_model_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>DotNetIT_ECCbundle_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>ProofOfConecept</method>
                </dotnetit_eccbundle_model_observer>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_save_before>
    </events>
```

when i update something in my cart the following is logged in my ProofLog.log file

```
2015-09-25T09:05:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): ProofOfConecept called - 2
2015-09-25T09:05:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): $cart contains data!
2015-09-25T09:05:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): $items has the following --
```

As you can see, the if statement is true that there does appear to be data in $items, however i cant seem to log the items, is this the correct syntax?

I cannot debug the project either, this code lives on production hence why I'm using Mage::log() for my debugging :(

Also I'm a .net web dev, and php magento is all new to me, last couple weeks I've been trying to learn as much as i can, so forgive me if the issue is a simple syntax mistake.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace the following line

```html
Mage::log('$items has the following -- '.$items, null, 'proofLog.log');
```

with

```html
Mage::log('$items has the following -- '.print_r($items), null, 'proofLog.log');
```

you will get all details in array and do whatever after that

Let me know if you have any query

Comment: the log now says 2015-09-25T10:18:27+00:00 DEBUG (7): $items has the following -- 1, however the page that triggers the event on refresh, spews out tons and tons of code on the web page.

Answer (score 0):

Replace following line

```
Mage::log('$items has the following -- '.$items, null, 'proofLog.log');
```

with

```
Mage::log('$items has the following -- '.print_r($items,true), null, 'proofLog.log');
```

this should print $items as string instead of array in log file.
It should work for you.